# Wrap the words by comma not by space with in html div

Tags: css, word-wrap

I have a requirement for wrap text using comma(,). Is there any way to do this using CSS or other.

```
Nomal A1, High A2(4), Low A3
```

If the space is not enough this should be wrap like this, comma should be the only wrapping place.

```
Nomal A1, High A2(4),
Low A3
```

this should not be wrap like this

```
Nomal A1, High A2(4), Low
A3
```

Answer (score 7):

Wrap each pair in spans, and style them not to break, like so.

Html

```
<div class="paired-text">
<span>Nomal A1,</span> <span>High A2(4),</span>
        <span>Low A3</span>
</div>
```

Css

```
.paired-text span{ white-space: nowrap; }
```

Alternatively, you could render a non-breaking space ( `&nbsp;` ) between each pair of words you want to stick together. I prefer the first idea I offer though, it's cleaner.

```
Nomal&nbsp;A1, High&nbsp;A2(4), Low&nbsp;A3
```

It's a little uglier, but it's less code.

Comment: The second idea has the problem that it does not prevent IE from breaking before an opening parenthesis “(”.

Comment: Thanks for the &nbsp; idea. simple solution to my problem

Answer (score 4):

The safest way is to use the [`nobr` markup](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html) (which never made its way to any spec but keeps being the most reliable method for the purpose):

```
<nobr>Nomal A1,</nobr> <nobr>High A2(4),</nobr> <nobr>Low A3</nobr>
```

Using a little more verbose `span` markup and CSS code `white-space: nowrap` is almost as reliable, but naturally fails e.g. when CSS support is disabled in a browser.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I solved my problem using your suggestion. It worked fine to me.

Comment: Underrated answer. Works like a charm. I had to use `</br>` after each of the sets of `<nobr>` tags though to get them on different lines.

Answer (score 0):

While CSS has a [`word-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-wrap) property, there are no options to wrap based on characters. Generally speaking, CSS is limited to styling.

You will need to do this with a client-side technology that is aware of the viewport and can manipulate the DOM, i.e. JavaScript.